# Numpy is installed but can't import multiarray

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to make `openface` work.

Here is the instruction to do setup.

```
>conda config --add channels conda-forge
>conda install opencv numpy pandas scipy scikit-learn scikit-image dlib txaio twisted autobahn OpenSSL pyopenssl imagehash service_identity
```

I removed numpy and reinstall to make sure numpy is installed.

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages
openblas-0.3.3       | 13.7 MB   | ##################################### | 100% 
numpy-1.15.4         | 8.9 MB    | ##################################### | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

So numpy is installed.
But I tried to import numpy and have error as

```
(openface) nyan@nyan-Inspiron-7537:~$ python
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2017, 17:05:42) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name multiarray
>>>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: to see the result of `which python`. maybe the `python` you are using is the system built-in one, not the one from `conda`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be the right `python` executable, as it prints Anaconda in the version string. But the numpy path in the error message is "/usr/lib/..." which is probably not your Anaconda path.

You should remove the broken system numpy, if possible, and make sure that you are using the conda environment properly, see [Managing environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).